# Retrieving values from an inner class with dot notation

Tags: apex, api, wrapper-class

I have a JSON payload I'm processing from a REST API web service in Salesforce. I converted the JSON to a DTO object in APEX with the following:

**WorkOrderDTO Class**

```
global class WorkOrderDTO extends DTO {

    public List<LineItem> OrderItems {get; set;}

    public class LineItem {
        public string Service {get; set;}
    }
}
```

**WorkOrderAPI Class**

```
public class WorkOrderAPI {

    WorkOrderDTO WO = (WorkOrderDTO) JSON.deserialize(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(), WorkOrderDTO.class);

    for(Object lineItem :  WO.OrderItems){
        String service = String.valueOf(lineItem.Service);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I attempt a simple dot notation like through the `lineItem` inner class, I get the following error message:

> Variable does not exist: Service

I believe I had this working at one time previously so I feel like I'm just missing a small detail. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should typecast lineItem variable as well before using as a plain object like below:

```
WorkOrderDTO.LineItem li = (WorkOrderDTO.LineItem)lineItem;
String service = String.valueOf(li.Service);
```